# Where can I find examples of research misconduct reports?

Tags: ethics, research-misconduct, reproducible-research, whistleblowing

I am writing a report documenting evidence for research misconduct. The report is to be submitted to the ethics board of a university. Are there publicly available examples of such reports? Not the formal investigation results but the actual report that triggered the investigation. I want to get an idea on how these are usually written.

Answer (score 3):

Retraction Watch has a separate section for these:

- [misconduct investigations](http://retractionwatch.com/category/by-reason-for-retraction/misconduct-investigations/)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is at the link and how that helps OP with their question, please?

Comment: The OP asked, "Where can I find examples of research misconduct reports?" I think I have answered his question? Is there need to elaborate further?

Comment: There is no need; it was just a suggestion. (For instance, I might suggest to edit "these" for "misconduct reports" and add a link and/or a description of what Retraction Watch is for those who are unaware.)